# Include custom post type custom taxonomies in Categories widget

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, theme-development

I wanted to see if this was possible, but I want to include the custom post type custom taxonomy categories inside the WordPress Categories widget.

I know that there is a filter as shown below:

```
add_filter('widget_categories_args', function() {
    $params['post_type'] = array('post', 'recipe');
    return $params;
});
```

1. My taxonomy is called `recipe-categories` inside `wp_term_taxonomy` and I want to be able to pull in all the categories inside the Categories Widget.
2. `recipe` is my custom post type.
3. Url string is `taxonomy=recipe-categories&post_type=recipe`

Here are all the categories that I have:

[image]

All that I'm getting back is the `post` categories and not my `recipe` categories as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The widget class uses [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) which supports all the [parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) for `get_terms()` like `taxonomy` which you can use to make the widget lists categories in a taxonomy other than `category`.

So your code would be:

```php
add_filter('widget_categories_args', function( $params ) {
//  $params['post_type'] = array('post', 'recipe'); // post_type is not a standard parameter for get_terms()
    $params['taxonomy'] = 'recipe-categories';
    return $params;
});
```

However, the widget only supports *a single taxonomy* because `wp_list_categories()` uses [`taxonomy_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/taxonomy_exists/) which doesn't support multiple taxonomies. Here's the relevant code in `wp_list_categories()` which causes the limitation:

```php
if ( ! taxonomy_exists( $parsed_args['taxonomy'] ) ) {
    return false;
}
```

So if you want to use multiple taxonomies, then you'd need a plugin for that (i.e. one that provides a similar widget) or you can code your own widget class.